# Martingale Problem - Markov process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, markov-process

Let $X$ be a right continuous Markov process with left limits and generator $L$. Why is $f(X_t)-f(X_0) - \int Lf(X_s) ds$ a martingale for every $f \in D(L)$?

Let s<t. $E^x[M_t^f|F_s]= E^x[f(X_t)-f(X_0)- \int_0^t Lf(X_r) dr |F_s]$  $= E^x[f(X_t)-\int_s^t Lf(X_r) dr |F_s]-f(X_0)- \int_0^s Lf(X_r) dr\\$.

It remains to show that $E^x[f(X_t)-\int_s^t Lf(X_r) dr |F_s]=f(X_s)$. I'm not sure how to go on from here. Perhaps I can start with $ E^x[f(X_t)|F_s]-E^x[\int_s^t Lf(X_r) dr |F_s]= E^x[f(X_t)|F_s]-E^x[\int_0^{t-s} Lf(X_{r+s}) dr |F_s] =E^{X_s}[f(X_{t-s})]-\int_0^{t-s}E^{X_s} (Lf(X_r)) dr $.

Comment: What attempts have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Please review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on providing context in your question to better assist the community.

Comment: Let s<t. $E^x[M_t^f|F_s]= E^x[f(X_t)-f(X_0)- \int_0^t Lf(X_r) dr |F_s]$  $= E^x[f(X_t)-\int_s^t Lf(X_r) dr |F_s]-f(X_0)- \int_0^s Lf(X_r) dr\\$. 

It remains to show that $E^x[f(X_t)-\int_s^t Lf(X_r) dr |F_s]=f(X_s)$. I'm not sure how to go on from here. Perhaps I can start with $ E^x[f(X_t)|F_s]-E^x[\int_s^t Lf(X_r) dr |F_s]= E^x[f(X_t)|F_s]-E^x[\int_0^{t-s} Lf(X_{r+s}) dr |F_s] =E^{X_s}[f(X_{t-s})]-\int_0^{t-s}E^{X_s} (Lf(X_r)) dr $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{T_t\}$ be the semigroup of $X$, i.e. $T_tf(x) = E_x f(X_t)$. Then by Markov property $$E_x [f(X_t)\mid  F_s] = T_t f(X_s), \qquad s<t. $$

As $Lf = \frac{d}{du}T_u f\mid_{u=0}$,  by the semigroup property of $\{T_t\}_t$ we have $T_r L f =  \frac{d}{du}T_u f |_{u=r}$.

So
$$ E [ \int_s^t Lf(X_r)  d r \mid F_s] = \int_s^t T_r Lf(X_s) d r = T_tf(X_s) - T_sf(X_s).$$